# Is there a command to point nuget.exe to a specific NuGet.Config file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to install Nuget packages via the cmd because our program runs on multiples VMs which chosen randomly. Some of these VMs have Nuget installed and have a NuGet.Config file which installs the packages in a folder my project cannot detect.

I created my own NuGet.Config and put in the root of my project folder, I tested it locally and everything works fine. I want something like "nuget.exe -configfile NuGet.Config" so that the packages will be installed in my project folder as I configured. Any help?

Comment: Is this a problem with the restore command? Could you show us what is working fine?
It seems to me you need something like:
nuget.exe restore -ConfigFile .\NuGet.Config
Is that what isn't working?

Comment: @jcespinoza Thanks very much, I didn't write the full command as you just wrote, now it's working.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT My bad. I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Based on [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-restore), the NuGet CLI accepts an option to indicate which config file to use. The syntax goes as follows:

`nuget.exe restore -ConfigFile <a-path-to-the-config-file>`

In your case:

`nuget.exe restore -ConfigFile .\NuGet.Config`

Based on the details on your question, the "restore" part was all that it was missing.